# Recursion with dynamic arguments

Tags: javascript, recursion

This was an interview question which I haven't yet been able to figure out. Consider the following:

```
function recurse(a) {
    return function(b) {
        console.log(a + b);
    }
}

//This will log '5' in the console
recurse(2)(3);
```

Now I was asked to write a function that will take `n` number of arguments and work the same way by logging the final summation of the argument values. Meaning:

```
//This should log '13'
recurse(2)(3)(1)(7)
```

How can such a function be written? I have tried thinking over it in terms of recursion, dynamic arguments etc. But haven't been able to write down anything concrete.

Comment: Um you do not call recursive functions this way, it needs to call itself to be recursive. When you do `recurse(2)` you effectively return `function(b){console.log(a+b)}` that is aware of the `a = 2` which you passed to it's closure. You are not getting the result via recursion.

Comment: This is currying of variadic functions and a bad idea. You should write that as an answer.

Comment: @Dellirium And yet, the general solution (for `n` curried arguments) will be recursive!

Comment: @this-vidor idk whay do you refer to here, the above code throws an error when called with more then 2 arguments

Comment: @Dellirium You haven't read the question, which asks exactly how one would create such a function for an arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: @Dellirium I am not sure of the solution or how to even describe my problem. My puny brain seems to think of recursion since I am multifolding  what the single level function returns.

Comment: Currying. Interesting, I didn't know this term exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the simplest version I could think of:

```js
function add (a) {
  return function (b) {
    return b == null ? a : add(a+b);
  }
}

console.log( 
  add(2)(3)() 
);
console.log(
  add(10)(100)(1000)(4)() 
);
```

In es6, it's compact!

```
let add = a => b => b == null ? a : add(a+b);
```

#### Note

The trouble with your question is that a function can **either** return a `Function` **or** a `Number`. The following code:

```
let result = add(2)(3);
```

is equivalent to:

```
/*1*/ let partialResult = add(2);
/*2*/ let result = partialResult(3);
```

In line 1, `add` doesn't know whether it is being called with the last argument or not! In other words, it doesn't know whether `partialResult` should be a number, or a function that will be called with another argument.

Nina Scholz gives you a solution where `partialResult` will behave like a number when treated like a [primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive), and like a function when called like a function. In my solution, `partialResult` always acts like a function, and returns a sum when called without an argument.

The first approach requires a language-specific mechanism for "behaving like a number" under certain conditions. If your interview was about JavaScript, it's the best approximation! But in a language-agnostic context, what you are asking for is impossible.

Comment: Prettier? That looks unreadable. Less code != easier to understand.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Changed the wording; now it's just "compact"! :)

Comment: It returns a function, not the sum. But I must agree it looks pretty neat.

Comment: @RutwickGangurde Yes, in this version you get the final sum by calling that function with no arguments, as shown in the code snippet.

Comment: Ohh right, I didn't notice that. Let me check it.

Comment: Works! Excellent. Thanks a lot @this-vidor

Comment: I have been looking for the same answer as well. Thanks to @A.Vidor.

Answer (score 6):

You could return the function and implement `toString` and `valueOf` methods.

```js
function recurse(x) {
    var sum = x;  

    function f(y) { 
        sum += y;
        return f;
    }; 
    f.toString = function () { return sum; }; // for expecting string, 1st log
    f.valueOf = function () { return sum; };  // for expecting number, 2nd log

    return f;
}

console.log(recurse(2)(3)(4));
console.log(recurse(2)(3) + recurse(4)(5));
console.log(recurse(2)(40) == 42);  // converts to expected type Number
console.log(recurse(2)(40) === 42); // checks type Function
```

Comment: Why people always propagate this hack?

Comment: @LUH3417 What hack?

Comment: Well isn't changing the `.toString` and `.valueOf` considered a hack?

Comment: @Dellirium Not by me. It might be **useful** for the community if you included links to a relevant discussion of the subject.

Comment: @Dellirium: No, it's normal for objects to define their own methods, including those ones. But *this use* of that could arguably be called a hack, since `f = recurse(2)(3)` is **not** going to put `5` in `f`. The only reason we see `9` in the in-snippet console is that it calls `toString`; a real console shows a function (followed by its toString result).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder fair point.

Comment: this is solving the asked problem, but the actual problem is the requirement itself. As Nina showed you can modify the function that it looks (and kind of behaves) like a number, but it is none, and this might lead to problems, when using this thing. Because although `console.log(recurse(2)(3), recurse(2)(3)==5)` will show `5, true`, this will fail: `recurse(2)(3)===5`. and unless you also add a `toJSON`-function, this "number" will disappear on serialization. **conclusion:** best solution you can get for a problematic requirement, and most likely buggy (in it's usage, not implementation)

Comment: @Thomas Technically, this doesn't solve the assigned problem, since the function is supposed to do the logging itself! Since it was an interview question, I assume the spirit of the question is the general mechanism for currying an arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: It works, but I can see `function` along with the answer. Meaning `recurse(4)(4)(4)` prints `function 12` in the console.

Comment: @Thomas Your comment is actually the best answer!

Comment: Up-voting this answer. It's pretty close.

Answer (score 2):

It is not requested that the recursion actually ***returns*** anything. It should just ***log***.

And because the requirement is to ***log the final summation of the argument values***, we can assume that it's perfectly fine to log the intermediate summations as well (unless it was explicitly forbidden in the full problem statement).

So, I suppose the interviewer would have accepted the following solution. It may actually be what he/she was expecting, given the initial source code.

```js
function recurse(a) {
  console.log(a);
  return function(b) {
    return recurse(a + b);
  }
}

recurse(2)(3)(5)(7)
```

If you really want to display only the last summation, you can either:

1. Cheat a little by using a `console.clear()` (not my preferred solution):

```js
function recurse(a) {
  console.clear();
  console.log(a);
  return function(b) {
    return recurse(a + b);
  }
}

recurse(2)(3)(5)(7)
```

2. Use a combination of `clearTimeout()` and `setTimeout()`. Here, we take advantage of the single-threaded nature of Javascript which prevents the callback from being executed until the expression is fully evaluated.

```js
var t;

function recurse(a) {
  t && clearTimeout(t);
  t = setTimeout('console.log(' + a + ');', 0);
  return function(b) {
    return recurse(a + b);
  }
}

recurse(2)(3)(5)(7)
```

Comment: Awesome! I can pretty much get my head around this solution.

Comment: @RutwickGangurde I'm still curious to know whether it was explicitly stated that only the final summation should be displayed. I've just added a 3rd solution, BTW.

Comment: Nope, only that the input should be given in the particular pattern.